# Magento 1 : How to know which cron run first

Tags: magento-1.9, cron

I have setup 2 cron for same time At 08:45 on every day-of-week from Monday through Friday

Lets assume there are two cron **A** and **B**

Cron A change status of order and in Cron B I want to use that changed status to do some calculation

How can I insure that cron A call first and cron B call after that

I know I can change **cron** timing to 08:45  but I want to if there is any sort order I can set for **cron** in **magento 1**

Answer (score 0):

I think you can set order of cron by customisation and overriding. We set the 
highest priority to our task in this.You can check out the following article

https://www.webinse.com/blog/add-sort-order-for-cron-jobs-in-magento/